# Can't fine tune a pre-trained model with dropout layer in keras

Tags: python

I have used vgg model without top layer and loaded 'vggface' weights. I have used this model as feature extractor and I have freezed its weights. Than, I have created the following model:

```
conv_base2 = VGG16(weights='vggface',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(64, 64, 3))

last_layer = conv_base2.output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc6')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc7')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
out = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='fc8')(x)
custom_vgg_model = Model(conv_base2.input, out)

custom_vgg_model.trainable = True
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv1_1').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv1_2').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv2_1').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv2_2').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv3_1').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv3_2').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv3_3').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv4_1').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv4_2').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv4_3').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv5_1').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv5_2').trainable = False
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv5_3').trainable = False
```

I have trained the mode. After that, I have tried to fine tune the model.

```
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv4_1').trainable = True
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv4_2').trainable = True
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv4_3').trainable = True
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv5_1').trainable = True
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv5_2').trainable = True
custom_vgg_model.get_layer('conv5_3').trainable = True
```

Then I have trained the model again and  have encountered the following error:

*Node 'dropout/rate' expects to be colocated with unknown node 'dropout_2/cond'*

By deleting the dropout layers, It works correctly, but overfitting happens. 
Does any one know what the problem is?

Comment: What Keras version are you using? Do you have installed both TensorFlow and Keras?

Comment: Tanks for your answer. I have used keras version 2.31 and  tensorflow version 2.0.0-alpha.

Comment: Please use all the imports like from tensorflow.keras.models import  instead of from keras.models import, replace everywhere and tell me if the problem still persists.

Comment: I have already done that. It works perfectly without dropout layer.